# Access just the current BuildConfiguration in a Build Definition

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, tfs-2015, azure-pipelines

Here is the setup:
I have a vNext Build Definition that I have set "Multi-configuration" to true and am using the Variable "BuildConfiguration".

```
BuildConfiguration = QA, UAT, Live
```

When the code is checked in, I get three builds, one for each of the configurations.

Here is what I am trying to do:
Unlike the Release Manager that has a field for 'NAME' which I can set very easily, the only option I have for the name to be displayed in the queue is to set the build number format under General.  I want to add the current BuildConfiguration being used for the given build with the build number.  I tried using:

```
$(BuildConfiguration) - Build.BuildNumber => QA, UAT, LIVE - 1234
BuildConfiguration - Build.BuildNumber => BuildConfiguration - 1234
```

Does anyone know how to access the current item being used in a comma separated list variable or is this just not possible?

I should point out, I am looking for this:

```
QA - 1234
UAT - 1234
LIVE - 1234
```

Comment: @jessehouwing, why did you edit my question?  There is a huge different between a vNext Build Definition and XAML Build Definition.

Comment: Ok fair enough, thank you for the clarification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could reproduce your scenario. Unlike Release that have multiple environment, in Build, although we have selected Multi-configuration, it's still in a single build, so you only can get one build name.

[image]

Comment: I am assuming that when you enable Multi-configuration and provided the Multipliers, it knows to split the results of the variable up on the comma whereas in the rest of the build definition it treats the variable as a single string?  Is there no way to access the Multiplier value?